# better way to authenticate user login in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-registration, authentication

I came across these two ways of `authenticating` username and password in `Django`.
which is preferred method and why?

One way:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

if request.method == 'POST':
                form = LoginForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                        drinker = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                        if drinker is not None:
                                login(request, drinker)
                                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
```

Other way:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class MyModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        print "My Logic"
        return super(MyModelBackend, self).authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you register your custom backend, the call to `authenticate` in your view will be authenticated against `MyModelBackend`

> Django tries authenticating across all of its authentication backends.
>   If the first authentication method fails, Django tries the second one,
>   and so on, until all backends have been attempted.

The examples in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/), also suggest that `MyModelBacked` needs to implement a `get_user` method as well

I believe, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/) clearly explains what subclassing `ModelBackend` does, and how to do it successfully